# Engenvalues of $I_{T}+AA^{\prime }$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maxima-minima

Suppose $I_{T}$ is a $T\times T$ identity matrix, and $A$ is a $T\times m$
matrix where $m<T.$  What's the properties of the eigenvalues of $I_{T}+AA^{\prime }?$ $^{\prime }$ is the transpose. Can we find the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $I_{T}+AA^{\prime }$? Thanks!

Comment: Well, the minimum is clearly $1$.  Not sure whether anything can be said about the maximum.  (I'm assuming that the prime notation means the Hermitian conjugate.)

Comment: Sorry, the prime is simply the transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = U\Sigma V^T$ be the singular value decomposition of $A$. Then $I_T + AA^T = U(I_T + \Sigma\Sigma^T)U^T$ is the eigendecomposition of $A$. The diagonal matrix of eigenvalues has the block form
$$
I_T + \Sigma\Sigma^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 + \sigma_1^2 & &\\
               & \ddots &\\
& & 1 + \sigma_r^2
\end{array}
& O_{r\times(T-r)}\\
O_{(T-r)\times r} & I_{T-r}
\end{bmatrix},
$$ 
where $r \leq m$ is the rank of $A$. Thus, the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ is $1$ which has algebraic multiplicity $T - r$ and the largest eigenvalue is $1 + \sigma_1^2$. Using matrix norm inequalities you can obtain the following upper bound on the maximum eigenvalue:
$$
\lambda_\max = 1 + \sigma_1^2 \leq 1+\sqrt{\|I_T + AA^T\|_F^2 -2\|A\|_F^2 - T}
$$
Naturally, many other such upper bounds are possible depending on what norm you choose.

Comment: Many thanks. This is indeed very helpful! One short question, what does $\sigma^2_1$ stand for in your notation? The minimum or maximum eigenvale of $AA^{\prime}$? Thanks

Comment: $\sigma_1$ is the maximum singular value of $A$.